# How Update data Quickly into Temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on Store Procedure Where I am having one Temporary Table with

```
DECLARE @DM_BR_ABC TABLE (PK,Column1,Column2,...Column40)
```

In First qry I am Inserting 200 thousand Records to my table after this.

after this I have another table

```
DECLARE  @DM_BR_XYZ (PK,Column1,Column2)
```

this table is fill by another Query 
with 200 thousand records 
Upto this there is no issue related to performance .....................
after this I am updating table @DM_BR_ABC Like this

```
 Update A  set A.Column2 =B.Column2 from @DM_BR_ABC A ,@DM_BR_XYZ B
 where A.Column1 =B.Column1
```

Here I am facing the issue .This sql statement taking too much time 2-3 hrs to update ....I have tried many solutions Like  `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the starting of the Store Procedure but its not working 
I am using Ms SQL Server 2012
So need Help for this .....

Comment: Have you set index on `Column1`?

Comment: Try to use join in the query.

Comment: Do you mean Indexing ?

Comment: Use an actual temporary table and not a table variable for starters...

Comment: @user2813816 : `@` tables are capable of having index. Put index on joining column ie `Column1` and try again

Comment: yes, indexing on column which used for where condition

Comment: Explain more on the problem and provide sample queries, you might not require  any table variable to all for these manipulation.

Comment: Use a #temp_table rather than @table_variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest writing the query using explicit `join`:

```
Update A
    set A.Column2 = B.Column2
    from @DM_BR_ABC A join
         @DM_BR_XYZ B
         on A.Column1 = B.Column1;
```

Now, `column1` is not a primary key in `B`, so there might be many matches.  You might try:

```
Update a
    set Column2 = b.Column2
    from @DM_BR_ABC a join
         (select column1, max(column2) as column2
          from @DM_BR_XYZ b
          group by column1
         ) b
         on a.Column1 = b.Column1;
```

Alternatively, you can add an index on `column1`.  Obviously, a unique index will not do, but you can define a unique index on `(column1, pk)`.

You can see how many rows are being processed by doing:

```
select sum(cnt)
from @DM_BR_ABC a join
     (select column1, max(column2) as column2, count(*) as cnt
      from @DM_BR_XYZ b
      group by column1
     ) b
    on a.Column1 = b.Column1;
```

This might give you an actual idea of how much work is being done.

Comment: @user2813816 . . . What does "not working" mean?  What is the total number returned by the last query?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a primary key and/or unique constraint on column1 of the table variables, which SQL Server *might* use to improve performance by making use of the underlying index for more efficient data access and perhaps yield a better plan since the cardinality is known.

However, table variable indexes do not have statistics so SQL Server estimates a single row during compilation. With a large amount of rows like this, you will likely get better performance with a temp table instead of table variable, especially if you have a clustered index (unique if possible) on the joined columns. Be aware that you might not get the results you expect if column1 is not unique.